# Fusionar 2 scripts: da error "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object"

Tags: php, imagen, clase, script

Hola hace dias que le doy vueltas a un script y no lo consigo. Estoy intentando fusionar 2 scripts;

1. Uno, es para un registro con subida de imagen (la guarda en una carpeta asociada a un id con mkdir)
2. El otro script es para tratar la imagen con una clase (  crea a la vez una imagen grande y un thumbnail)

La idea es que se cree la carpeta para cada id del registro (script 1), y dentro de cada una se guarde la imagen grande y el thumbnail.(script 2)

Por separado funcionan, pero juntos me arroja el siguiente error:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object ...on line 57

No domino mucho PHP, no sé ni donde ni como colocar el segundo script dentro del primero.  Agradeceria cualquier explicacion para un novato. Si algien sabe fusionar los scripts mucho mejor. Gracias

Adjunto los 2 scripts :

SCRIPT 1:

```
// cargamos el archivo
if($_FILES["archivo"]["error"]>0){
    echo "Error al cargar archivo"; 
    } else {

    $permitidos = array("image/gif","image/png","image/jpeg");
    $limite_kb = 2000;

    if(in_array($_FILES["archivo"]["type"], $permitidos) && $_FILES["archivo"]["size"] <= $limite_kb * 1024)
                  {

        $file = $_FILES["archivo"]["name"];
        $ext=substr($file, strrpos($file, '.'));  
        $ruta = 'files/'.$id_insert.'/';
        $archivo = $ruta.time().$ext;

        //creamos la carpeta y se guarda imagen en directorio.

        if(!file_exists($ruta)){ 
            mkdir($ruta);

        if(!file_exists($archivo)){
            $resultado = @move_uploaded_file($_FILES["archivo"]["tmp_name"], $archivo);

            if($resultado){
                echo "Archivo Guardado";
                } else {
                echo "Error al guardar archivo";
            }

            } else {
            echo "Archivo ya existe";               
        }           
        } else {
        echo "Archivo no permitido o excede el tamaño";
    }       
}   ?>
```

SCRIPT 2:

```
<?php
include("../src/class/class.upload.php");

$archivo = new upload($_FILES['imagenes']);

if ($archivo->uploaded) 
{
    $archivo->image_resize              = true; // default is true
    $archivo->image_x                   = 1000; // para el ancho a cortar
    $archivo->image_ratio_y             = true; // para que se ajuste dependiendo del ancho definido
    $archivo->file_new_name_body        = time(); // agregamos un nuevo nombre  
    $archivo->jpeg_quality                = 90;
    $archivo->process('img/content/user/'); 
 echo 'La imagen a sido recortada';



    $archivo->image_resize              = true; // default is true
    $archivo->image_x                   = 100; // para el ancho a cortar
    $archivo->image_ratio_y             = true; // para que se ajuste dependiendo del ancho definido
    $archivo->file_new_name_body        = "t-".time(); // agregamos un nuevo nombre     
    $archivo->process('img/content/user/thumb/');   
 echo 'La imagen a sido recortada';

} 
else 
{
    echo 'error : ' . $archivo->error;
}   
?>
```

Comment: Si ambos scripts hace funciones diferentes de cada uno, lo ideal es tenerlos así en dos archivos diferentes, porqué los ocuparías en un solo archivo?

Comment: y entonces como los relaciono entre ellos?

Comment: No entiendo a que te refieres con fusionar los 2 scrips, y para que quieres hacerlo

Comment: El primer script guarda la imagen tal cual original y crea una carpeta asociada a un ID de usuario.( pero no hace thumbnail ni nada).  El segundo script redimensiona la imagen y la guarda en 2 tamaños a través de la clase 'class.upoad.php. ( pero este no guarda en carpeta con ID) . La idea es crear  un script que haga todas las funciones en uno solo.

Comment: ¿Qué sucede en tu segundo script si por ejemplo pasas $archivo->image_resize=false, $archivo->image_ratio_y=false, $archivo->file_new_name_body  = "original-".time(), y $archivo->process('img/content/original/');